# Entity Framework Sql Azure mapping error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

### Setup:

Asp.NET Web Api 2 (Running in Azure Cloud service, 3 instances), Entity Framework 6.1 and Sql Azure

### Problem

My application started reporting a ton of weird errors all of a sudden.

When using EF to get entities from the database these types of errors are reported:

"The '{PropertyName}' property on '{TableName}' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int64'"

And

"The '{PropertyName}' property on '{TableName}' could not be set to a 'System.Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'."

My interpretation is that the database is returning non-matching objects compared to what I'm trying to map against, but I can't see why that would start happening out of the blue, after running just fine for millions of requests.

While I was writing this I rebooted the api instances and now the errors are gone.

Any help in figuring this out will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the origin of the exceptions? Are you sure they're not from API methods that had not been addressed before?

Comment: Hi, yes, I am sure about that. The methods are being called rougly 10 times per second and had been running fine for days before this started.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the probable cause was a mistake in the setup of the unit of work pattern. Note to self: Do not create a new dbcontext to replace a dbcontext that is being used :)